# NASM x86_64 printf 7th argument

Tags: assembly, stack, printf, x86-64, nasm

I have a simple `dprintf` program written in NASM which prints a long format with more than 6 arguments. I am passing the arguments as the calling convention requires (*RDI*, *RSI*, *RDX*, *RCX*, *R8*, *R9*). As long as I use only those my program works fine.

I can't figure out why I get a segfault each time I try to push something to the stack as additional arguments. Here is the source:

```
;a comment
%macro DATA 0
section .data
    string: db "%6$ca comment%1$c%4$cmacro DATA 0%1$csection .data%1$c%2$cstring: db %3$c%5$s%3$c, 0%1$c%2$cpath: db %3$cGrace_kid.s%3$c, 0%1$c%4$cendmacro%1$c%4$cdefine SC_OPEN 0x2000005%1$c%4$cmacro MAIN 0%1$c%1$cDATA%1$c%1$csection .text%1$c%2$cglobal start%1$c%2$cglobal _main%1$c%2$cextern _dprintf%1$c%1$cstart:%1$c%2$ccall _main%1$c%2$cret%1$c%1$c_main:%1$c%2$cpush rbp%1$c%2$cmov rbp, rsp%1$c%2$cmov rax, SC_OPEN%1$c%2$clea rdi, [rel path]%1$c%2$cmov rsi, 0x0200%1$c%2$cxor rsi, 0x0002%1$c%2$cmov rdx, 0640o%1$c%2$cclc%1$c%2$csyscall%1$c%2$cjc ret%1$c%2$ccmp rax, 0%1$c%2$cjle ret%1$c%2$cmov rdi,rax%1$c%2$clea rsi, [rel string]%1$c%2$cmov rdx, 10%1$c%2$cmov rcx, 9%1$c%2$ccall _dprintf%1$c%2$cxor rax, rax%1$cret:%1$c%2$cleave%1$c%2$cret%1$c%4$cendmacro%1$c%1$cMAIN%1$c", 0
    path: db "Grace_kid.s", 0
%endmacro
%define SC_OPEN 0x2000005
%macro MAIN 0

DATA

section .text
    global start
    global _main
    extern _dprintf

start:
    call _main
    ret

_main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    ;sub rsp, 16
    mov rax, SC_OPEN
    lea rdi, [rel path]
    mov rsi, 0x0200
    xor rsi, 0x0002
    mov rdx, 0640o
    clc
    syscall
    jc ret
    cmp rax, 0
    jle ret
    mov rdi, rax
    lea rsi, [rel string]
    mov rdx, 10
    mov rcx, 9
    mov r8, 34
    mov r9, 37
    mov rbx, 59
    push rbx
    xor rax, rax
    call _dprintf
    xor rax, rax
ret:
    leave
    ret
%endmacro

MAIN
```

I assemble and link with these commands:

```
nasm -fmacho64 file.s
ld file.o -macosx_version_min 10.14 -lSystem
```

This works just fine but I would like to add extra parameters. I tried to push it on the stack using:

```
    mov rbx, 59
    push rbx
```

It segfaults whether I sub some bytes to *RSP* or not.

I am under MacOS Mojave and I'm using the latest version of NASM.

Comment: The second potential problem is that if this is on a system using the x86-64 System V ABI then you may need to ensure the stack is aligned on a 16 byte boundary just before you do `call _dprintf` .By pushing an 8 byte value on the stack you have misaligned the stack.You may have to adjust RSP by subtracting 8 from RSP before `push 59` (and then add 16 to RSP after the `call`)

Comment: I see at the very bottom of your question you did mention MacOS. Sorry for my earlier request about what platform you were on. As well ignore my comment about `_dprintf`, I assume you are calling the system one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , indeed I am using the system one, and I am using  commands nasm -fmacho64 file.s 
then ld file.o -macosx_version_min 10.14 -lSystem to obtain my program, I will try your alignement solution !

Comment: I still segfault no matter what,  I tried to do a sub rsp, 16 right after mov rbp, rsp, then push my value just before printf call , the push opcode still the one that makes my program segault.
Lldb doesn't give me any clue either , I am not an expert of how to use debugger

Comment: I get the same issue with 8, 16, 32, and 48, I really can't figure out why.

Comment: Sorry , I will edit the post with complete code ! thank you for your help again, Some of the constraint are project requirement such as the use of macro. If you remove the sub rsp, 8 to push rbx lines, it works fine. I still have to modify my format string but globally it does what it should except that I can't add 7th and 8th parameters to dprintf

Comment: In your string you have `%5$s` .You do realize that prints a string that requires a pointer? Maybe you meant `%5$c` for a character?

Comment: no it's fine, that's the tricky part where I print the format itself to copy the exact source code . Actually the pointer and the 59 value that is ';' for the comment part, are the things I am trying to figure out how to push it onto stack. I was initially trying to do something like :
lea rbx, [rel string]
push rbx
mov rbx, 59
push rbx

Comment: %5 is not the format.You give it a character (the value 59). A string is not a character. For `%5$s` to work you need to pass `dprintf` a pointer to a string not a character as the 5th variadic parameter.

Comment: It's %5$s that is the 5th parameters after format, so the 7th parameter to dprintf. In c it would be like : dprintf(fd, format, 10, 9, 34, 37, format, 59); 
I can refer to each parameter in format with %n$[csd...] where n is the parameter emplacement , 1 for 10, 2 for 9 , etc 
I Placed 10 in rdx, 9 in rcx, etc but for format and 59, I can't figure the solution to pass it to dprintf.

Comment: I got what you mean, oh wait I give it a try !

Comment: Oh thank you VERY MUCH , it finally works, indeed %s is waiting for a pointer that couldn't works with 59, I am stupid ! 
I start to understand the stack basis...!

Comment: indeed the 16 byte initial space is enough if I understand well. also the reverse order twisted my mind !

Answer (score 2):

Your format string contains `%5$s`, which means it will try to print the 5th vararg (the 7th arg overall) as a string.  Since that 5th argument is the constant 59 (presumably the character constant `';'`) and not a string, this ends up crashing inside printf (generally, inside strlen called from printf)

Answer (score 2):

Since this question ended up having some value it probably could use an answer. There are two significant problems:

- You call [`_dprintf`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dprintf) with 7 parameters that have the *C* equivalent of:

  > ```
  > dprintf (fd, format_str, 10, 9, 34, 47, 59)
  > ```

  The problem is that in your format string you have `%5$s`. The 5th *variadic parameter* is the value 59, not a pointer to a string. `dprintf` is trying to access memory it doesn't have permission to and you get the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS and a segment fault. You also have `%6$c` in the format string but don't have a 6th *variadic parameter*. From your comments it became clear you wanted the `format_str` itself to be the 5th parameter and the value 59 to be the 6th. The code to push the last 2 parameters should have looked like:

  > ```
  > push 59
  > lea rbx, [rel string]
  > push rbx
  > xor rax, rax
  > call _dprintf
  > ```

  The corresponding *C* call would have been:

  > ```
  > dprintf (fd, format_str, 10, 9, 34, 47, format_str, 59)
  > ```

  **Note:** When pushing the parameters on the stack that don't fit in the registers they must be pushed in reverse order
- The [x86-64 System V ABI calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) requires at least 16-byte alignment of the stack before making a call to a conforming function (that includes the *System* and *C* library). On MacOS the System library is very sensitive to stack alignment issues as it uses aligned SIMD instructions wherever it can for performance reasons even when using just integer class parameters.

  `_main` conforms to this standard as well. The ABI requires 16-bye alignment at the point just before a call. 32-byte alignment is required if you pass parameters requiring 256-bit SIMD vectors - but that is not the case here. After entering `_main` (or any function that complies with the x86-64 calling convention rules) the stack is misaligned by 8 because the *return address* is now on the stack. `push RBP` subtracts 8 from RSP and the stack is now aligned on a 16-byte boundary again. If you push an even number of parameters on the stack to satisfy a call like `dprintf` alignment will still be intact. If you pass an odd number you are misaligned once again. In those cases you have to subtract 8 from RSP before pushing parameters.

  If you had truly meant to do:

  > ```
  > dprintf (fd, format_str, 10, 9, 34, 47, 59)
  > ```

  You would have had to subtract 8 from RSP prior to pushing the extra 1 parameter on the stack. The code would have looked like:

  > ```
  > push rax         ; Push any register on stack or use `add rsp, -8` to align parameters
  > push 59
  > xor rax, rax
  > call _dprintf
  > ```

  In the case where you pass 2 extra parameters to `dprintf` no such stack adjustment is required as an even number of parameters being pushed will not break the 16-byte alignment